# JMS Connection Pooling in J2SE environment

Tags: jms, connection-pooling

I am looking for a JMS connection pooling library in J2SE environment. Spring seems to provide org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory, which maintains a single connection and a pool of sessions. For my scenario, I need to maintain a pool of JMS connections that will be reused by multiple threads. Note that this program runs in a command line and not in the application server. Is there any library available for this purpose? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms. It was forked from the ActiveMQ JMS Pool and enhanced to provide JMS 2.0 functionality.

Comment: Thanks Justin for the link.

Comment: Hi Justin, this question came up when I was looking to understand the difference between pooled connections and sessions. I noticed that you had already answered this here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52279513/7430088. The reply says that both the approches are functionally equivalent. Can you help me understand how?

Comment: By "functionally equivalent" I mean that although the inner workings may be slightly different the ultimately behavior will be essentially the same. In the project I linked in my answer both the connection pool and the session pool are implemented using org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool so if you have a single connection with multiple pooled sessions verses multiple connections each with their own session the behavior from the client's perspective will essentially be the same - JMS resources managed by a pool.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again for the your prompt reply

Comment: If you think this answer is correct please mark it as such to make it clear for users who may have this same question in the future.